# SQL Server nested transaction with multiple database

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

I have 2 databases. DB_Global, and DB_01

I have two stored proc one in DB_Global and one in DB_01.

Both the sps has BEGIN TRAN, COMMIT TRAN, and ROLLBACK if any exception occurs.

SP from DB_01 is calling SP for DB_Global twice for setting a table(in global database) column to: 1  on start & 0: on End.

I have noticed transaction in the GLobal database is not getting committed properly. Column value remains 1.

Do we need to follow any different approach to handle a transaction which has the dependency from multiple databases?

I am using synonyms to call sp from different databases. And not give any specific names to each transaction.

Comment: Sample SQL is really going help here. you might want to consider naming your Transaction too. Don't forget you can use a variable's value for it, if you want to make sure it's unique. For example `DECLARE @TranName varchar(50) = 'SPNameTran_' + REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(30),SYSDATETIME()),' ','_'); BEGIN TRAN @TranName; ....; COMMIT TRAN @TranName` Is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: It's working now. It was not a logical issue. Actually Later we figure out that column was being set immediately by another process.
Thanks @Larnu for you comment.
Will be closing this thread now.

Comment: Nested transactions are a myth. They are just like a unicorn. Avoid this common mistake. Here is a great article that explains the true evils and misconceptions of "nested transactions". https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/ And cross database transactions require a LOT of work.